# AVR GCC compile error using _SFR_IO_ADDR as a constant expression

Tags: gcc, avr

In a C++ program I need to get the address of an I/O register as a constant expression that can be passed as an integer in a template parameter. In GCC 5, this worked:

```
static constexpr uint16_t Address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA);
```

However, GCC 6.3.0 produces the following error:

```
error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer
```

Here's a summary of definitions in AVR libc:

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0x20

#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)

#define _SFR_MEM_ADDR(sfr) ((uint16_t) &(sfr))
#define _SFR_IO_ADDR(sfr) (_SFR_MEM_ADDR(sfr) - __SFR_OFFSET)

#define PORTA _SFR_IO8(0x02)
```

What is a working approach to extract the register address as a constant expression integer?

I suspect something can be done with macros by "parsing" the definitions, but I only see how to remove the first set of parentheses and not how to deal with the asterisk.

**EDIT**: The case where it actually fails is this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
struct PortDef {
    static const uint32_t Address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA);
};
```

Here's the command used and the error:

```
$ ~/avrgcc/bin/avr-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from /nix/store/43k8vl3dzm102wj1jsdb1sil9k5b0k6r-avr-gcc-libc/lib/gcc/avr/6.3.0/device-specs/specs-avr2
COLLECT_GCC=/home/ambro/avrgcc/bin/avr-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/nix/store/43k8vl3dzm102wj1jsdb1sil9k5b0k6r-avr-gcc-libc/libexec/gcc/avr/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: avr
Configured with: ../configure --target=avr --prefix=/nix/store/43k8vl3dzm102wj1jsdb1sil9k5b0k6r-avr-gcc-libc --disable-nls --disable-libssp --with-dwarf2 --disable-install-libiberty --with-system-zlib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: single
gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC) 

$ ~/avrgcc/bin/avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega2560 test.cpp -c -o test.o
In file included from /nix/store/43k8vl3dzm102wj1jsdb1sil9k5b0k6r-avr-gcc-libc/avr/include/avr/io.h:99:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
test.cpp:3:37: error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer
     static const uint32_t Address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTA);
```

It does not fail in these cases (so these are simple workarounds at least in GCC 6.3):

- Address is defined in namespace scope instead of in a class.
- It is defined as part of a class but the value is defined outside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the difference between `constexpr` and `const`, but `const` seems to work in this case.  The following code compiles for me:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
static const uint16_t address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB);
```

I used that macro successfully in [this library](https://github.com/pololu/pololu-led-strip-arduino/blob/master/PololuLedStrip.h).  And, by the way, I think you can use a `uint8_t` instead of `uint16_t`.

Here is a shell session from my Arch Linux system showing that the code above can be compiled with avr-g++ 6.3.0:

```
$ avr-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/avr/6.3.0/device-specs/specs-avr2
COLLECT_GCC=avr-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: avr
Configured with: /build/avr-gcc/src/gcc-6-20161222/configure --disable-install-libiberty --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-linker-build-id --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-gold --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-ld=default --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-shared --infodir=/usr/share/info --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --prefix=/usr --target=avr --with-as=/usr/bin/avr-as --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/bin/avr-ld --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-gnu-indirect-function
Thread model: single
gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC)
$ cat test.cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
static const uint16_t address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB);
$ avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega328p test.cpp -c -o test.o && echo success
success
```

Comment: I am getting an error with const as well. Note that this is when compiling as C++ with GCC 6.3. I know GCC 5 does not have the issue.

Comment: I am doing the same and it works for me.  I just added my full shell session so you can check my work.  Maybe you could run `avr-g++ -E` on your file to see what that problematic line is getting expanded to by the preprocessor.  For me, the right-hand side of the assignment expands to: `(((uint16_t) &(PORTB)) - 0x20)`.

Comment: I tried this out and yes it works. I found what doesn't is if you put it in a class:  `class Test { static const uint16_t address = _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB); };`

Comment: It also works if you put it in a class but define the value outside the class.

Comment: Well it's hard for me to fix the problem you are having with `const` since I have not been able to reproduce it.  More details about how exactly you are trying to compile the code would help (e.g. see the shell session I posted above which shows exactly how I compiled my code).  But it sounds like you found a solution anyway.

Comment: I added the full example to the question, you should be able to reproduce it. Anyway we now have two workarounds and I consider the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this issue by generating a header file defining the numeric addresses of specific registers. Here's the [actual code](https://github.com/ambrop72/aprinter/commit/7184fd8aa23be72546009e714da38605c8d19133).

It works like this:

- There is a file which contains uses of different register macros (e.g. `PORTA`). It is not valid C++ but after preprocessing it results in lines such as `REG_PORTA:<definition>;` where `<definition>` is what `PORTA` expands to.
- The preprocessed file is transformed into definitions such as `static uint16_t const Address_PORTA = <address>;` where `<address>` is the numeric address which was extracted by stripping all the casts from the original expression.

I use preprocessing with the same defines and compiler flags as I compile with to ensure that the right register definitions are used. This is more portable than parsing the original device-specific header files since you would need to know which header file is correct.

Caution: the result of this are memory addresses, equivalent to `_SFR_MEM_ADDR`. To get the IO address of IO registers (`_SFR_IO_ADDR`), `__SFR_OFFSET` must be subtracted.